# Strange selenium value return

Tags: c#, selenium, phantomjs

I;m using Selenium with PhantomJsdriver

```
 using (IWebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver())
    {                   

                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");                   

               var  content = driver.PageSource;  >> wrong content return
    }
```

content always get `"<html><head></head><body></body></html>"`

but `driver.PageSource` is properly get the full site content.

What's wrong that? Really strange behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are experiencing an issue with timing. The content is retrieved before the entire `DOM` content is loaded. The easiest way to check for that is to add `Thread.Sleep(2000)` before retrieving content. This however is not a good practice so utilize the events that the driver provides you with before retrieving content, or wait for a specific `DOM` element to be loaded before retrieving content.

Comment: thanks for prompt reply but it's not right as i can view both values in my debug point (using Visual studio), really strange, hover on both content and driver.pagesource, they show different values. I believe all DOM content is fully loaded , otherwise, i cannot view the driver.PageSource the full page content.

Comment: ok, i tried 2000, maybe too fast, so i increased to Thread.Sleep(10000), the variable content now get the right value. thanks.